# Using a result (table from sas entrep guide) into sas miner

Tags: sas

In SAS Miner, I would like to use a result/table from SAS entrep guide.

So far, I managed to save this result/table into sas studios.

In SAS Miner, when creating a data source, I have to select a SAS table or a metadata repository. I select Sas table then I am stuck as I can not access my source

It would be great if you know know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Save the data set into a location available to both the server used by Enterprise Guide and SAS Enterprise Miner.  If they are the same server, great, put it into an easy to get to location.

After that, you will need to create a library reference to that location in Enterprise Miner.  The specifics of that I am unsure of (I don't have a version to play with), but you administrator should be able to do that for you.  If not, that's a good question for SAS Tech Support (which is free since you are a client).

Comment: In this case, what would be the location available to both entep guide and sas miner? When i try to save the data set on my desktop , a pop up message appears :" local SAS is required for exporting as a SAS data file"

Comment: Somewhere on the server.